# NDK, JNI and libcurl

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk, libcurl

I've taken over a project and am having a hard time implementing the SSL side of things. Our application makes use of libcurl to access remote content from a server. The device is looking for a cacert.pem file to which I have, but am unsure where to place it. I've tried to place it in the root of the application but that did not help.

Co workers suggested the file should be placed directly into /sdcard but that did not help either.

Does anyone know where I should place the cacert.pem file within the application to enable it to be used by libcurl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify where libcurl looks for the CA information using `curl_easy_setopt` with `CURLOPT_CAINFO`:

```
  static const char *pCACertFile="cacert.pem";

  /* ... */

  /* set the file with the certs vaildating the server */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, pCACertFile);
```

The following example demonstrates a full SSL session, including specifying the CA certificate file:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, but the location of the cert is already coded. Its where Android is actually looking for the cert on the OS side of things when libcurl is called.

Comment: What are you setting the location of the cert to?

Comment: the location of the cert is "cacert.pem"

Comment: Try calling getcwd() and getting the current directory. I'm not sure what the default cwd is for Android apps, but it's likely `/data/data/packagename`.

You could try setting the value of the the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option to `/data/data/packagename/lib/cacert.pem`, and dropping the cacert.pem in the lib folder of your application.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I did try including the cacert.pem file directly in the applications's root but I'm unsure if it was copied into the APK. I will probably try and add it after.

Comment: Great, setting the cacert.pem file location to ./cacert.pem and including it directly in the root of the Android project (not in res, or otherwise) worked.

Comment: copying it in the root of my Android project didn't work for me, but I managed to solve the issue by putting the file in my assets folder and extracting it to the app's files folder on first run.